# What could cause wpmu_create_blog to throw "Already Installed" Error on multisite?

Tags: multisite, hooks

I have a production website https://toursoft.co which when we do dev work we move it to https://toursoft.us and do a database search replace to setup the dev environment.

This is a multisite environment.

Calling `wpmu_create_blog()` programmatically throws the following error (it's actually not an error but returned HTML)

`Already Installed
You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first.`

Once this happens one time, it is no longer possible to create blogs in the system, even via Sites > Add New in the Network Admin area. The error continues to pop up.

On a woocommerce hook, we have custom code to create a new blog in the multisite programmatically, with this code:

```
$domain = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'My Field', true );
$domain .= '.toursoft.us'; 
$path = "/";

// we've passed all validation checks up to this point so create the new site.
$new_blog_id = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, 'Adventure Tours', $subscription->get_customer_id());
```

Despite the error, an entry is made into wp_blogs database table. There is, however, *not* an entry in wp_signups, and I'm not sure if that's relevant.

What is the code checking (or database entry) that causing that error? How can I reverse it?

UPDATE: After tracing that error that issues as far as I could go, I noticed in the file MS-FUNCTIONS.PHP there are two functions that wpmu_create_blog uses - `insert_blog` and `install_blog` in that order.

`install_blog` on line 1443 is calling `if ( $wpdb->get_results( "DESCRIBE {$wpdb->posts}" ) )`

$wpdb->posts is set as 'wp_posts' and not 'wp_NUMBER_posts' that's typical for a new blog. I'm not sure why its id is not being set.

Comment: What debugging have you performed so far? What are debugging results you're seeing in your error logs? What is the value of $new_blod_id; errors return an WP_Error object?

Comment: @Steve I mentioned above, but basically there isn't an error being thrown, formally I mean. I can find the line of the code where that's being thrown and I can see why - it's failing on checking to see if that table exists. But it's checking the wrong table. I'm not sure how I can more deeply debug it, so I'm open to suggestions.